# Android studio debugger : ExecutionException

Tags: android-studio, executionexception

Running debugger, but the Event log console print:

ExecutionException: Execution finished.

And I try to restart. But it don't work.

Comment: Does it provide any exception log?

Answer (score 1):

Disable Android NDK Support And Restart Android Studio.